# Opening a file in python gives the error IOError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: '' on MAc

Tags: python, macos, python-2.7

I run a code frequently for a task of mine, but this is the first time I ran it on Mac and it gives me the error -

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "bt.py", line 103, in <module>
    with open(filename,"a") as fout:                        
NameError: name 'filename' is not defined
```

The code is -

```
import time
from datetime import datetime, timedelta
import re
import zipfile
import glob, os
import string


str=""
new_name=""
new_name1=""
date_folder_name=""
flag=0 
file_name=""
file_name2=""
filename=""
line2=""
lines=""
i=0

path=""
clock=""
device=""
command=""
commandName=""
data=""

#..\input\BT
inputBTFolder=os.path.join('..','input','BT')

#Extracting Zip File and Storing Date
for root, dirs, files in os.walk(inputBTFolder):
    for file in files:
        if '.zip' in file:
            print("Processing:"+file)
            file_name=file.split('.zip')[0]
            file_name2=file_name.split('_')
            zip=zipfile.ZipFile(os.path.join(inputBTFolder,file))
            zip.extractall(os.path.join(inputBTFolder,file.split('.zip')[0]))

            year='20'+file_name2[6]
            month=file_name2[5]
            date=file_name2[4]
            Date=date+"-"+month+"-"+year
            dateformat=datetime.strptime(Date,'%d-%m-%Y')
            clock=dateformat.strftime("%Y%m%d")+"000000"


        for root, dirs, files in os.walk(os.path.join(inputBTFolder,file_name)):
            for file in files:
                f=open(os.path.join(root,file), "r")
                for line in f:
                    crInfo='CR INFO'
                    #i=0
                    if 'Connecting to ' in line :
                        deviceName=line.split(" ")
                        device=deviceName[2]
                        print device

                        path=os.path.join('..','output','British-Telecom','cli',clock,device)
                        if os.path.exists(path):
                            continue
                        else :
                            os.makedirs(path)

                #Code for each device starts from here -
                if 'executing' in line:
                    commandName=line.split("'")
                    command=commandName[1]
                    if ("/" or "*" or ":" or "%" or "-" or "|" or " " in command) :
                        if("|" in command):
                            commandname1=command.split("|")
                            command=commandname1[0]
                        command=command.replace("/", "_")
                        command=command.replace("*", "_")
                        command=command.replace(":", "_")
                        command=command.replace("%", "_")
                        command=command.replace("-", "_")
                        command=command.replace(" ", "_")

                        if("__" in command):
                            command=command.replace("__", "_")
                        if(len(command)>0 and command[-1]=='_'):
                            command=command[:-1]

                        filename=path+"/"+command+".txt"
                        open(filename,'a').close()


                if crInfo not in line:
                    with open(filename,"a") as fout:                            
                        fout.write(line)
```

Could you please let me know what's the issue I'm seeing with Mac and how do I resolve it?

Comment: your title does not agree with traceback

Comment: also this doesn't seem to be [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve), I recommend you to start from [How to ask?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)

Answer (score 0):

I just tried your file on my iMac and it didn't run to completion. It gave an error message for line 58 which was the statement `print device`. Python 3 and above require print statements to have parenthesis so your line should be `print (device)`. The other computer you ran it on might have used python 2 while you Mac was maybe using python3. I added parenthesis to the print statement and your code ran to completion. So maybe you want to fix the print statement and see if that helps.

I ran it in VScode and also from the terminal. It ran to completion in both cases with no error messages. There was no output at all as far as I could tell. I suppose this script runs on another file I don't have. So my run to completion is probably not reliable. However, I did not get any error messages so maybe that tells you something.